# ListFragment activated item background

Tags: android, android-listview, android-support-library, android-listfragment

I have a ListFragment with default layout and I use setItemChecked to check the items. On Honeycomb and ICS the checked rows automatically have the background color applied as I am using `simple_list_item_activated_1` layout. How do I achieve the same effect on pre-HoneyComb devices? Neither `state_activated` nor `activatedBackgroundIndicator` are available on older platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know of is to create a custom adapter with a public boolean array that keeps track of the checked state of the items in the list and uses that array to control the background color of the list item in your `getView`.

```
if (checkedstate[position] == true){
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); 
} else {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); 
}
```